# Dynamic input from cells

Tags: excel

I need to do the following, (I will use an example to make it simpler)

Let's assume that cell's A1 value is 10, and represents number of coin flips.
Then I want in column B to have 10 cells waiting for the result of each coin flip.
B1 = "Coin Flip 1", B2 = "Coin Flip 2" ... B10 = "Coin Flip 10"

But if I change A1 from 10 to any other number I want column B to change correspondingly, (i.e. if A1 = 5 I want B1 = "Coin Flip 1", ..., B5 = "Coin Flip 5" )

I am sure that this has been asked again, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy down as many rows as you will ever want to display, or just fill the entire column with it:

```
=IF(ROW()<=$A$1,"Coin Flip " & ROW(),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was so simple! Using <= in the logical test is exactly what I want.